# Why no integer value in a pointer straight?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int* ptr = NULL;
    *ptr = 10;
    printf("%d", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I am very new to C programming and sorry in advance if it comes off ignorant.
I am trying to put a value, acceessing pointer variable which is assigned to NULL but it does not work.

My guess is that this is because *ptr is supposed to point some array, or variable's address, cannot contain the value itself without pointing anything.

Is my understaning correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. NULL means "nothing" here, so no memory is assigned to the pointer. You need memory to store something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your understanding is correct, you cannot do what you code tried to do

```
int main(void)
{
    int* ptr = NULL;   <<== creates a pointer that points noweher (null)
    *ptr = 10;      <<== store 10 where that pointer points
    printf("%d", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

In the second line you try to store 10 where 'ptr' points. But 'ptr' points nowehere, the result is whats called Undefined Behavior. Typically your program will halt right there

You can do this instead

```
int main(void)
{
    int* ptr = NULL;  <<<=== create pointer to nothing
    int val = 0;       << == create int with value 0
    ptr = &val;       <<<== set ptr to point at val
    *ptr = 10;        <<< ====overwrite val with 10
    printf("%d", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

the line

```
 *ptr = 10;
```

does the same as though you did

```
 val = 10;
```

---

You can also do

```
int main(void)
{
    int* ptr = NULL;  <<<=== create pointer to nothing
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(int); <<<== set ptr to point at dynamically allocated int
    if(ptr==NULL) return -1; <<<=== make sure it worked
    *ptr = 10;   <<< === now set that dynamically allocated int to 10
    printf("%d", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that unlike the previous example  there is no other way to refer to that `int`. (You could use 'val' and '*ptr' interchangeably before)

Comment: How about adding an example with malloc too? Or at least mention it

Comment: @EricPostpischil it depends on your understanding of their final phrase of that final sentence, but yes maybe I can fix my wording

Comment: Thank you for all the comments and discussion.

Answer (score 0):

> My guess is that this is because *ptr is supposed to point some array, or variable's address, cannot contain the value itself without pointing anything.

That is correct; `*ptr = 10;` will not change where `ptr` points, so you must set it to point to usable memory first.

`int *ptr = NULL;` initializes `ptr` to a *null pointer* value, which is a value that essentially means “nowhere.” It is some value that is unequal to the address of any object or function. (Most commonly, C implementations use a “zero address” for a null pointer.)

You can set `ptr` to point to usable memory in several ways:

```
int x;
ptr = &x;     // This sets ptr to point to x.

int a[17];
ptr = &a[3];  // This sets ptr to point to a[3].
ptr = &a[0];  // This sets ptr to point to a[0].
ptr = a;      // This also sets ptr to point to a[0].
```

In the last example, the array `a` is automatically converted to a pointer to `a[0]`.

You can also allocate memory dynamically:

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
if (ptr == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, unable to allocate memory.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Calling `malloc` asks the system to reserve memory. If it succeeds, the address of the memory is returned. If it fails, a null pointer is returned, and you should always handle that possibility by testing after calling `malloc`. You can `#include <stdio.h>` to declare `fprintf` and `#include <stdlib>` to declare `exit` and `EXIT_FAILURE`.

After any of the above, you can execute `*ptr = 10;` to store 10 in the place where `ptr` points.

When you use allocated memory, you usually want to free it when you are done with it. You can do that by calling `free(ptr)`.

`malloc(sizeof *ptr)` allocates enough memory for one object of the type `ptr` points to. You can allocate memory for `N` objects with `ptr = malloc(N * sizeof *ptr)`. After that, if the call succeeds, you can store values in `ptr[0]`, `ptr[1]`, … `ptr[N-1]`.